# Bash disagrees with my pipes, refuses to do the full command

Tags: bash

This is my code so far:

```
#! /bin/bash

Options=("1" "2" "3")
select opt in "${Options[@]}"
do
  case "$REPLY" in
     1)
        who=$(whoami)
        echo -e "you are: $who"
        ;;
     2)
        var=$(uptime | awk '{print $3}' | cut -d, -f 1)
        echo $var
        ;;
     3) break;;
     *) echo "Invalid input";;
  esac
done
```

It doesn't work. The first option works just fine. The second one however doesn't.

Further testing suggests bash doesn't like piping much, the output is simply "#", suggesting it's only the awk part of the command that actually gets executed. The command just works fine out in the shell (it reports the time it has been online only).

Comment: Why do you have a `$` in `$echo`? What about backticks around the whole line?

Comment: That would be a typing error, there's not supposed to be any echo on that line at all. Will update.

Comment: Did you mean like this: var=´echo uptime | awk '{print 3}' | cut -d, -f 1´ ?

Doesn't work says "cut: invalid byte or field list"

Comment: To be honest, I am not sure. I followed these guys examples: http://askubuntu.com/questions/1705/how-can-i-create-a-select-menu-in-a-shell-script

I see now I've forgotten to change opts to REPLY.

Works anyway though. Might be it's not really that important? My other option still works.

Comment: @summea

cut away the comma at the end so it only gives the time and nothing else

Comment: I fixed the missing dollar problem, now my script will only print a new line, the "3" is now completely absent. And yes, I did remember the "cut" in my actual code. Like I said, I don't like the comma at the end so it had to go. Will update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line doesn't make any sense:

```
var=$(uptime | awk '{print 3}' | -d, -f 1)
```

The `awk` statement should be

```
awk '{print $3}'
```

and the `cut` statement should be

```
cut -d ',' -f 1
```

To be honest, you probably don't need the `awk` statement at all for what it seems you want to do. Just pipe `uptime` to the `cut` statement above.

```
var=$(uptime | cut -d ',' -f 1)
```

Comment: That'd return first time, followed by the actual uptime. I want to only see the uptime, without the comma. Which is surprisingly difficult.

Comment: @user2230627 If I run `uptime` on my system, I get `23:40  up 22 days, 21:01, 2 users, load averages: 0.37 0.41 0.45`. **What do you want to see from this?**

Comment: **NB** The question has been revised since this answer was posted.  A review of the edit history shows that the original code was as quoted in this answer.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, the OP has made numerous changes to his code. The comment history is littered with futile attempts to get him to post his actual script.

Comment: Fixed it! Allthough I am unsure how. Hang on a sec.

Comment: I am not entirely sure, but I think the problem was this: The old code read "uptime | awk '{print 3}' | cut -d, -f 1" assigned to a variable. The correct code was all about adding that dollar sign. I probably hit the wrong keys while typing it into my ubuntu VM, resulting in what seemed to be irrational errors. As always they they were logical. It now seems the only change I truly needed was that dollar sign. Now, how do I change the question to solved?

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you use a text files from Windows/Dos and reuse it in unix.

The line terminators in each respective OS are different.
HTH

p.s. You'll notice a ^M at the end of a line when you open the text file in vi/vim.

> Doesn't work says "cut: invalid byte or field list" – user2230627 Apr 1 at 3:34
>
> :